# Plane point rotation to a specific plane

Tags: math, three.js, rotation

I have a system where one axis is moving from [0 -> 2PI]. This movement generates an angled plane. [Axis movement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5qKWY.gif).

This yellow plane will be my target plane. I know the normal vector of this yellow plane and its constant. For me to calculate XYZ position on the yellow plane based on the rotation value of the axis (tool). I've come to a "solution" to first calculate what is the XYZ coordinate for a simpler plane [vertical plane [1 0 0] as normal vector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aaDio.jpg) as I know the sphere origin and also the radius then it is easy to calculate any XYZ position based on the axis angle.

But my probelm is that now that I have the XYZ position on the gray plane: how can get my XYZ position to the corresponding position on the yellow plane? [From gray plane to yellow plane](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8NI6.jpg) Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Solution to this was simple.. I made it more complicated than necessary. There wasn't any need for transforming the points from one plane to another as these values could be calculated easily from the sphere origin and the plane orientation values.

```
// calculate axis rotation to radians
let radAngle = (angle)*Math.PI/180;
let beeta = (90*Math.PI/180) - radAngle; //rotation value on the circle
let gamma = Math.acos(yellow.normal.x); //plane orientation

// temporary vars
let cb = Math.cos(beeta); 
let sb = Math.sin(beeta);

let cg = Math.cos(gamma);
let sg = Math.sin(gamma);


let x = sphere.origin.x + sphere.radius*(cg*sb);
let y = sphere.origin.y + sphere.radius*(sg*sb);
let z = sphere.origin.z + sphere.radius*cb;
```

[Rotation sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ecZAb.gif)